# A combinatorial identity No. 2

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I have no idea how to simplify ( if possible at all ) this sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{x}{n-k}\binom{y-2x}{k}2^k$$

It would be fine if a 1-binomial expression formula would result.

Comment: I assume this is function in $x$ and $y$?

Comment: $y$ is an given integer and $x$ is then in the range from $0$ to $\frac{y-1}{2}$ e.g. if $y$ is odd and .in the range from $0$ to $\frac{y}{2}$ e.g. if $y$ is even.

Comment: How do you mean "e.g."? If $y$ is an integer, $y$ being odd or even is exhaustive, not exemplary?

Comment: Of course - you are right. $y$ is an integer.

Comment: Have you looked at [the Wolfram|Alpha result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20%28-1%29^k%20*%20binom%28x%2Cn-k%29%20*%20binom%20%28y-2x%2Ck%29%20*%202^k%20for%20k%3D0..n&dataset=)? I'd be surprised if you can do better than that. Also relevant: [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) -- but I don't see how to generalize it usefully to your case with a factor $q^k$ included.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** I agree with @Joriki's     comment  and I want to provide some reasoning why we don't expect to get a closed formula for OP's expression.

> We do so by *translating* the problem into a representation with polynomials and comparing it with the *[Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%5C%27s_identity)*. While the polynomials in case of Vandermonde's identity can be easily transformed to a simple polynomial giving a closed binomial expression, we will see that this is not the case in OP's problem. As Joriki stated, the main reason is the factor $2^k$.
>
> For convenience only we substitute $y-2x$ with $y$ in OP's expression and consider
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{x}{n-k}\binom{y}{k}2^k\qquad\qquad n\geq 0\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Since according to the binomial theorem

\begin{align*}
(1+z)^x=\sum_{k=0}^x\binom{x}{k}z^k
\end{align*}
we can write $\binom{x}{k}$ as the coefficient of $z^k$ in $(1+z)^x$. We use the  *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[z^k]$ and can write
\begin{align*}
\binom{x}{k}=[z^k](1+z)^x\qquad\qquad k\geq 0
\end{align*}

> **First step:** Vandermonde's Identity
>
> Before we analyse OP's expression let's have a look at *Vandermonde's Identity*
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{x}{n-k}\binom{y}{k}=\binom{x+y}{n}\qquad\qquad n\geq 0\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> We start with the LHS of (2) and obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{x}{n-k}\binom{y}{k}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}[z^{n-k}](1+z)^x[w^k](1+w)^y\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}[z^{n}]z^k(1+z)^x[w^k](1+w)^y\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^{n}](1+z)^x\sum_{k=0}^{n}z^k[w^k](1+w)^y\tag{5}\\
> &=[z^{n}](1+z)^x(1+z)^y\tag{6}\\
> &=[z^{n}](1+z)^{x+y}\\
> &=\binom{x+y}{n}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we write the binomial coefficients as coefficients of corresponding polynomials
- In (4) we use the identity $[z^{n+k}]f(z)=[z^n]z^{-k}f(z)$
- In (5) we rearrange the sum to prepare for a substitution in the next line
- In (6) we consider (generally a formal series) $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k$ and observe
  \begin{align*}
  f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left([w^k]f(w)\right)z^k
  \end{align*}
  noting that $a_k$ is the coefficient of $w^k$ in $f(w)$.

> **Conclusion:** We see, it's easy to get a closed formula since the polynomials $(1+z)^x(1+z)^y$ can be nicely combined to $(1+z)^{x+y}$.

Now let's consider OP's expression.

> **Second step:** OP's expression
>
> We proceed precisely as above and obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{x}{n-k}\binom{y}{k}2^k&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}[z^{n}]z^k(1+z)^x[w^k](1-2w)^y\tag{6}\\
> &=[z^{n}](1+z)^x\sum_{k=0}^{n}z^k[w^k](1-2w)^y\\
> &=[z^{n}](1+z)^x(1-2z)^y\tag{7}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (6) we collect $(-1)^k2^k\binom{y}{k}$ and note this is the coefficient of $w^k$ in $(1-2w)^y$.
- In (7)  we observe that  $(1+z)^x(1-2z)^y$ can't be further simplified.

**Conclusion:** Due to the expression (7) we don't expect to derive a closed formula.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment and I don't know if this is useful, but I tried to do it with Mathematica and it gave me:

> $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

Which in `TeXForm`, yields:

$$\frac{ \, _2F_1(-n,2 x-y;-n+x+1;-2) x!}{n! (x-n)!}$$

Where $_2F_1(a,b;c;d)$ and `Hypergeometric2F1` are this [hypergeometric function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html). If you need a reference for hypergeometric functions, I guess you could read Knuth/Graham/Patashnik's: Concrete Mathematics. I'm posting it because perhaps you can find the concept interesting/useful.

Comment: I had this also in Wolfram Alpha in the formatted version. Is to advanced for me at this moment.